# Reading css file from nodejs

Tags: html, css, node.js

How do I get my css file to be read by node js. I have the html file read by the code below.

```
function displayForm(res) {
fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The same way you can do

**html**

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
});
```

**js**

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/js/script.js', function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
});
```

**css**

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/css/style.css', function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
});
```